# Implementing navigation that supports going back to a search result

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am looking to implement a search such that when the user presses a search result, the relevant `UIViewController` is pushed onto the search result itself, allowing the user to press back to view the search result again.

I have tried simply pushing the ViewController onto the presenting ViewController's `UINavigationController`. This results in the `UIViewController` appearing behind the search result (it can be seen when canceling the search result).

I have also tried subclassing `UINavigationController` and making it conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating`, proxying the updates to the `UIViewController`. This results in almost the correct behavior, but the search bar remains with the navigation bar when a view controller is being pushed onto the `UINavigationController`, as can be seen in the image below.

I could simply do some hacky code to hide/show the search bar depending on the state of the `UINavigationController`, but it seems like there must exist a cleaner way of accomplishing this.

Apple has themselves done this in their Notes app, if you do a search and press a result, you are brought to the relevant note, pressing back takes you back to the search result. So I am wondering how to replicate this behavior correctly.

[image]

Comment: "but the search bar remains and overlaps with the navigation bar when a view controller is being pushed onto the subclassed UINavigationController" - can you share a pic of what exactly is happening here?

Comment: I can't. I don't have enough reputation apparently.

Comment: Upload it to some image sharing site and give me the link

Comment: I've updated the question with a link.

Comment: add `definesPresentationContext = true` in `viewDidLoad` and give it a try

Comment: Tried adding it to the nav controller and search result without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later solved this the hacky way by making the `UIViewController` that is responsible for displaying the search result conform to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol (in addition to `UISearchResultsUpdating`). The `updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)` method then catches and stores a reference to the `UISearchController` that is passed as a parameter. Then this juggling with view-logic in the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` code makes everything work and look as expected:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewController == self {
        searchController.searchBar.hidden = false
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        searchController.searchBar.hidden = true
        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Lastly, as explained in the third paragraph above, I made a subclass of `UINavigationController` which is assigned as the search results controller, and which delegates navigation events and `UISearchResultsUpdating` events to the `UIViewController`.

This certainly works as intended and I not experienced any bugs with this so far. Will post an update if I find a cleaner solution next time I look over this code (might be easier in iOS 9).